# RegExp with square brackets replacing everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to replace all instances of `[1]` (including the brackets), but instead of replacing all instances of `[1]`, it's replacing all instances of `1`.

```
var index = 'abc123'
var regexp = new RegExp('[' + index + ']', 'g');
var new_id = new Date().getTime();

$(this).html().replace(regexp,'['+new_id+']')
```

Comment: escape the specials, bro. `[]` is a range selector, like `[a-z]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the brackets with `\\` characters.

Since you're writing a Javascript string literal, you need to write `\\` to create a single backslash for the regex escape.

Comment: I tried escaping the brackets, but it still replaces all instances of the `index` variable...brackets or not.

Comment: You also need to escape the `\​`s from the JS string literal.  I edited my answer.

Comment: Ah there we go. Didn't realize I needed the double slash. Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the brackets

```
var regexp = new RegExp('\\[' + index + '\\]', 'g');
```

Comment: I tried escaping the brackets, but it still replaces all instances of the `index` variable...brackets or not.

Comment: From the other answer I see the back slashes also need to be escaped.  Good catch, SLaks.  Just verified that double escaping  works in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var index = 'abc123'
var regexp = new RegExp('\\[' + index + '\\]', 'g');
var new_id = new Date().getTime();

$(this).html().replace(regexp,new_id)
```

I changed the last line of your code because it did change all [1]'s just added the brackets back in the replace function.
And also escape your brackets

Answer (score -1):

`[]` is special in a regex.  It defines a character class.  For example:

```
/[a-z]/
```

matches any letter, **a** through **z**.  Or:

```
/[123abc]/
```

matches **1**, **2**, **3**, **a**, **b**, or **c**.

So your regex:

```
/[1]/
```

Means to match any character of **1**.

What you need to do is escape the [ and ] like so:

```
/\[1\]/
```

Or specifically in your code:

```
$(this).html().replace(regexp,'\['+new_id+'\]')
```